# How can i write the below python code in a single list comphrension which also involves a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

```
states = { 1:['Alabama@ ', 'Georgia!', 'Geor%gia%%', 'georgia', 'FlOrIda', 'southcarolina##', 'West virginia?']}

def remove_punctuations(value):
    return re.sub('[#!?@%]','',value) # remove these punctuations 

for_strings = [str.title, remove_punctuations, str.strip] # perform these  actions on strings 

def clean_strigs(strings,options):
    result = []
    for val in strings:
        #print(val)
        for function in options:
            val = function(val)
        result.append(val)
    return result

filter_dictonary(states[1],for_strings)

output = ['Alabama',
 'Georgia',
 'GeorGia',
 'Georgia',
 'Florida',
 'Southcarolina',
 'West Virginia']
```

I am trying to write the clean_string function in a with comprehension and also trying to call for_list inside it but I am unable to do so I tried the below code

```
def filter_column(strings,for_strings):
    result =  [val for value in strings for function  in for_strings for val in function(val) ]
    return result
```

Can some help me with writing this?

summary: Just write the above clean_strigs in a single list comprehension

Comment: While list comprehension can definitely be used for the construction of the `result` list, using if for function composition is not something you cannot do very easily. You can use the  `functools.reduce` function to create a composed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below solution. It should work.

```py
result = [reduce(lambda a, func: func(a), [value] + for_strings) for value in states[1] ]
```

The problem with nested for loop in list comprehension is that result of the previous function will not propagate to the next function. That is where reduce comes to help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, mate for solving the problem

Comment: Smart solution - still would prefer mine over this - mine is far easier to understand in terms of whats going on if you revisit the code 4 weeks later to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehension is unsuited for the task at hand. This solves it:

```
def filter_dictonary(strings,for_strings):
    for f in for_strings:
        strings = map(f,strings)
    return list(strings)
```

If you fix this specific error in your function by doing this:

```
result =  [val for value in strings 
           for function in for_strings 
           for val in function(value) ]  # function(val) creates the error
```

it wont work because you then opeate on single chars and do not get the combination of the functions you are looking for.

Comment: @Sha what is giving the wrong output? The upper part works. the lower one CANT work because list comp do not propagate changes on the input between function calls, only the last one will be done - and you iterate on characters that way as well which is why your approach does not work. In regards to the accepted solutions - it works but it is also MUCH more complicated to understand than what my solution does. I would not use a complicates list comprehensions using reduce to replace the 3 lines of codes above.

Comment: Yes Sir you are right code readability is much more important